# setParameter vs setParameterList for lists in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Could someone please explain the difference between these two methods for lists in Hibernate? The name implies that we should use setParameterList for lists, right? But everything works perfectly fine with the setParameter method as well. So what's the difference? I've read [the javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setParameterList-org.hibernate.query.QueryParameter-java.util.Collection-) but it hasn't become clearer why should I prefer this method over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difference here in the way of how [Hibernate type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-types) of the parameter is detected.

1. For the `Query<R> setParameterList(String name, Collection values)` method:

> Bind multiple values to a named query parameter. *The Hibernate type of the parameter is first detected via the usage/position in the query and if not sufficient secondly guessed from the class of the first object in the collection.* This is useful for binding a list of values to an expression such as foo.bar in (:value_list).

2. For the `Query<R> setParameter(String name, Object value)` method:

> Bind a named query parameter using its inferred Type. *If the parameter is defined in such a way that the Type cannot be inferred from its usage context then use of this form of binding is not allowed*, and `Query.setParameter(String, Object, Type)` should be used instead.

**EDIT**

As you can see from the [implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/internal/AbstractProducedQuery.java#L491) of the `Query<R> setParameter(String name, Object value)` method:

```java
public QueryImplementor setParameter(String name, Object value) {
    getProducer().checkOpen();
    if ( value instanceof TypedParameterValue ) {
        final TypedParameterValue  typedValueWrapper = (TypedParameterValue) value;
        setParameter( name, typedValueWrapper.getValue(), typedValueWrapper.getType() );
    }
    else if ( value instanceof Collection && !isRegisteredAsBasicType( value.getClass() ) ) {
        setParameterList( name, (Collection) value );
    }
    else {
        getQueryParameterBindings().getBinding( name ).setBindValue( value );
    }
    return this;
}
```

It's equivalent to the `setParameterList(String name, Collection values)` method, if `value` is `Collection` and it's not registered [basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic).

Comment: But the type can easily be checked like this 
value instanceof Collection

Comment: Yes, you can see this exactly in the `setParameter`  implementation. See updated answer. I would suggest you to use `setParameter(String name, Object value)`  as more common way to set the parameter.